# Hmm... "add as link"ed images don't show up at runtime

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

Sorry guys, I [posted this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419530/why-does-the-image-element-give-me-a-design-time-error-with-add-as-linked-image) today where my "add as link"ed images were giving me a design-time error.  I got assistance with that and now my code compiles, but now the images don't even appear when my application runs.

Just for giggles, I changed the Build Action for the images, and nothing made a difference.

Is there anything I can do to debug this and figure out if there's a runtime error preventing me from displaying images?

This is the first time I've experienced this, because until today, I've always had my images in my project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [found my answer](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/08/linked-images-in-wpf-projects-cause-issues), and ironically enough, the person that answered my previous question suggested something there that would have helped me out here.

Synopsis: don't use linked images in your WPF app because they are not treated the same as images in your project folder.  This is a confirmed bug and will be fixed in VS2010.